# Change Maven pom.xml to workspace root

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

### USE CASE

Long story short, my git repo is configured in a manner, that not the workspace, but the project folder is checked out.

this means my pom.xml is at `/data/jenkins/workspace/pom.xml` and not at (as jenkins currently builds)
`/data/jenkins/workspace/{PROJECTNAME}/pom.xml`.

the problem is: Jenkins runs the following command on the slave:

```
mvn -B -f /data/jenkins/workspace/project/pom.xml jboss-as:deploy
```

digging a bit through SO i found i can explicitly change the working directory to check out to.
as this will not help in changing the generated path, who is nicely relative, i tried to give the force-path of maven directly. unfortunately this did not work the way expected, but instead resulted in a File not Found error.

i also tried to change the root pom in build configuration to:

> ../pom.xml
>   /data/jenkins/workspace/pom.xml

and out of ideas i ask a question here now.

*EDIT:*
i now specified both workspace and root pom.xml

> Workspace: /data/jenkins/workspace/
>   Root POM: /data/jenkins/workspace/pom.xml

in configuration there is no error shown, even still i get a InvocationTargetException with this as stacktrace:

> Executing Maven:  -B -f /data/jenkins/workspace/pom.xml jboss-as:deploy
>     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:331)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
>     at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
>     at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:112)
>     at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>     at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
>     at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
>     ... 17 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
>     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
>     ... 18 more
>     channel stopped
>     ERROR: Failed to parse POMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you breaking Jenkins workspaces directory structure so? Let Jenkins manage Jenkins. Use the Git plugin to let the job checkout into the workspace structure properly.

In the Advanced Section of a job you can change the workspace to /data/jenkins/workspace/ if you like, maybe your job will work as expected.

Comment: well i didn't set the Git up, and now i gotta get jenkins working :( please be patient with me ;)

Comment: i could finally find the correct property in the git plugin, which allowed me to checkout into a subfolder. thanks for your help